# PHP adding a counter

Tags: php

So yeah I have a search function where it searching based upon conditions such as which select option is chosen.

The query and all goes well, however while I am looping the data is it possible to say for example:

```
$count=0;
$count=+1;
echo $count;
echo '.';
```

As such the output would be 1. , 2.  and so on?

I am supposing it is possible, just wondering what is the best approach for something like that?

Comment: sounds like a job for something client side, not server side -some kind of "please wait" animated gif comes to mind

Answer (score 3):

Erm, you mean like this?

```
$count=0;
$count++;  //same as $count = $count + 1; or $count += 1;
echo $count;
echo '. , ';
```

Edit: This might be more helpful.

```
$echoStr = '';
while($some_condition) {
    $count=0;
    //$count++;  //same as $count = $count + 1; or $count += 1;
    $echoStr .= ++$count . '. , ';
}
$echoStr = rtrim($echoStr, ' , ');
echo $echoStr;
```

Note it trims off the last comma. Happy Coding

Comment: unless you clear the buffer i dont think this what the op had in mind.

Comment: It's not echoing out anything with that code.
For instance:
count=0
loop here
echo count++;
stop loop
So it's in a sense counting upwards from 1 so that it is in a way showing the amount of search results.

Comment: @user1868565 What exactly are you trying to do? The question is rather vague

Comment: number of search results? sorry the question seems to change every time you type. mysql_num_rows() ? count(id) in the query, to many possibilities

Comment: Well it would be just that no matter what? The only difference is that the counter is within the loop? And for as long the loop is going the counter will to.

Comment: @user1868565 what loop? do you really think you are giving us enough to go on here?

Comment: @user1868565 Could you edit your question and post more relevant code please? Like the whole loop that you are talking about

Comment: A loop that is looping data based upon the search results, but that isn't important. I think I've got it to work now.. The only difference between this answer and my question was that I was putting the counter inside a loop.

Comment: @Shredder You answered my question, I was just wondering basically how to create a counter that is within a loop, the loop itself isn't important. You gave me a answer :).

Comment: @user1868565 Cool. I made an edit I hope is more helpful. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Just looking over what I see in your code. It looks like your trying to make a integer which is +1 of the previous?

I'm not 100% because the lack of information; Add some information to your question and I will update this post accordingly; If this is something you are looking for:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;  /* the printed value would be
                   $i before the increment
                   (post-increment) */
}
```

Credits to the [PHP While Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php%202)

Comment: If this was the answer you was looking for, mark it as the answer by pressing the green tick; this will be at the top of the post for future reference